# MYSQL Query Optimization (need to increase speed)

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a MySQL Table that holds Google Analytics data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `analytics_data` (
  `ga_profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `page` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `medium` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `bounces` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entrances` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `new_visits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `page_views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unique_page_views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time_on_page` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `visits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  KEY `ga_profile_id` (`ga_profile_id`,`source`,`medium`,`date`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have a query to compute the sum of visitors based on a google analytics profile ID (ga_profile_id) over a given time period:

```
SELECT 
    SUM( `visits` ), ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( `date` ) - 21600 ) * 1000 AS date 
FROM `analytics_data` 
WHERE 
    `date` >= '2011-05-09' AND `date` <= '2011-06-08' AND `ga_profile_id` = [...]
GROUP BY `date`
```

We have 4.5 million records or so.

**Index Data:**

```
Type: BTREE
Fields/Cardinality:
ga_profile_id / 100
source / 10196
medium / 10196
date / 149893
```

**EXPLAIN SELECT**
- **id**: 1
- **select_type**: SIMPLE
- **table**: analytics_data
- **type**: ref
- **possible_keys**: ga_profile_id
- **key**: ga_profile_id
- **ref**: const
- **rows**: 219555
- **extra**: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

Average time for execution: **1 second**.

We are on a virtual private server and most queries get executed in .0003 - 0.03 seconds. LONG queries (that I was going to optimize at some point) are generally .3 seconds.

I have tried adjusting the keys, ignoring some, changing some values and nothing seems to be affecting it in a positive way. Considering this is 1 of many queries on a page.

I am looking at changing MyISAM to memory -- any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: What if you create a composite index `ga_profile_id + date`? Also `key_length` (if i remember correctly the name) from EXPLAIN could be useful

Comment: Your query is a bit odd: You'll get one grouping for every different second. Is that *really* what you want? It seems a very fine break down.

Comment: Have a look at the optimization tips called out in: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6236416/best-optimisation-tips-for-webservice-and-mysql/6237892#6237892.

Comment: @ zerkms, I showed all the information from the EXPLAIN -- that's all it had.

Comment: @Bohemian - I get one grouping for every date -- it's a date field, not a datetime :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create composite index `ga_profile_id + date` in this particular order. And you'll get the best you could get with such query.

Further possible optimization is to pre-calculate sum of visits per date and use that for fast calculations.

Comment: This dropped the query to .09 seconds. Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> I have a query to compute the sum of visitors based on a google analytics profile ID (ga_profile_id) over a given time period

It seems pretty optimized already... In your question at the time of writing this answer, you've stripped out the most interesting part of your query (the actual clause on `ga_profile_id`), which is the most selective in all likelihood -- hence the current index usage.

At the very best, you'd manage to leverage an index on `date` if you place it in a multicolumn index, e.g. `(date, ga_profile_id)` **or the other way around** depending on your usage pattern and table statistics.

See [indexes dos and donts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098616/dos-and-donts-for-indexes).

Comment: I thought I was using a multi-column index --there's 4 items in there ( the other 2 are for some other queries), but I could try removing them.

Comment: Are you sure the index should start from `date`? It is range condition in `WHERE` so second part will **never** be used for fast lookup.

Comment: Be sure to look into the order in which they're inserted. From left to right, selectivity -> order criteria. If you've something in between two columns that you're looking into, the index won't even get considered in MySQL (and in Postgres, you'll actually be better off with single column indexes and bitmap scans in the latter case).

Comment: @zerkms: I'm not at all hence the "or the other way around depending on your usage pattern and table statistics"

Comment: Thank you @Denis -- all this information has been very uesful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Running indexes will be the first and easiest option but if that doesn't help I would suggest to look more into some fundamental DB management strategies like Table Partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

@Kerry, look at Denis's solution... The only alternate to his offer is to have the index on PROFILE ID FIRST, THEN Date, otherwise, your index will be incorporated for anyone else too having action within the same time period...

In addition, @Bohemian's point of grouping down to the second is a strong point... you probably want to sort based on the DATE ONLY portion of a full date/time column result.

Comment: Denis's solution will not work, since it is range comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you have typical date ranges in your query then you may consider to partitionate your table horizontally. Maybe it also helps when most of your data is "outdated" and you only have the "fresh" ones you need on one or more partitions and all these old ones on another. [RANGE Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html)

Comment: It's always the last 30 days -- that's a great reference, but would it be possible to partition for the last 30 days, rather than "DATE LESS THAN" ?

Comment: First I've to say: Your query is now very fast. I would not recommend to use partitioning when you're happy now.

I know that MySQL had some issues with that, too. In comparison to Oracle database this is a "new feature" to MySQL and I do not know what issues still exist.

About the "last 30 days" thing: I am not sure, but I do not think it is possible since it would result in continious repartitioning.  But you can add a partition every month, year or so.